# How to stop Wifi from automatically turning itself off?

Tags: wi-fi

So on occasion, my wifi automatically turns itself off for some strange reason. This happens on both my Lenovo ThinkPad and my Samsung Galaxy S5. Is there a way prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 6):

Turn off Connection Optimizer

- Settings -> More Networks -> Mobile Networks -> Connections optimizer -> TickOff connections Optimizer

Or Turn Off Wifi Timer

- Settings -> Wifi -> Tap the vertical ... and then Advance -> Wi-fi timer -> Turn off any timer selected.

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings, Wi-Fi, (menu button) advanced settings and then select All the time on the option use Wi-Fi on suspension.

The translation maybe it's not perfect. My phone is in Spanish

Comment: Keep wifi on Sleep > Set always.

Answer (score 1):

Check your device setting... You your device is on power saving mode then this can happen as the more optimized mode switch off wifi when not in use.

I had similar issue with my HTC One which took some time for me to catch and fix.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In Wireless options in your Samsung device.
Click on options (Overflow-icon) and click Advanced. After that you'll see an option called "WiFi timer", click on it and uncheck both check boxes.

Does this happens on your devices who are connected to the same network or?
And does it happens on your, or any network.

And here is the link from Lenovo Support page, about [your problem](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-T400-T500-and-newer-T/ThinkPad-Wireless-keeps-disabling-itself-wireless-radios-being/ta-p/399541).

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of GPS as some settings for the GPS (aka high accuracy) use Wi-Fi & connect to known Wi-Fi connections to triangulate your position and can improve on location detection. To fix this:

- got settings
- location
- disable GPS by turning off

Hope this solves your issue

Comment: I don't think so. I turned on GPS and set it to high accuracy and it didn't enable Wi-Fi on its own.

Comment: Have you gone into settings -> app manager -> all tab and select settings and clear all data... ...I just recently had this issue today too how ironic

Comment: What does clearing data of Settings app has anything to do with this? Please clarify.

Comment: OK all apps store some form of data about where you are in a game (I e save file), in an app, what changes were made like adding Wi-Fi connection (I e ssid Random name and password, random password) as well as Bluetooth devices and basically anything else. Clearing all data would make it like the app was just opened for the first time

Comment: Never mind the dreaded Wi-Fi issue still prevails.on my phone I need to rethink

Comment: @Firelord OK I may have found a possible solution for it ***Only*** if you have Comcast / XFinity, the app XFinity Wi-Fi apparently has permission to toggle Wi-Fi on without user interaction so check it's settings and see if you can change it or uninstall the app altogether. And by the way the only reason I say XFinity Wi-Fi is because it's the only app I have tested as your results may differ in conclusion find the app in question to look and see if any apps can toggle Wi-Fi

Comment: Question is about "wifi is turning off automatically (during sleep)". Your answer is about the feature turning on wifi automatically based on location (where we use wifi often)

Answer (score -3):

Format your phone and check..
This happens due to a virus attack by installing various malware applications by unknown sources.

Comment: And what is your source of info for this claim?

Comment: anti-viruses are there so you could save your device  without reformating every time a virus hits.

Comment: Please show us the reference that states android has viruses. Malware/adware, yes. Viruses, no. Also please get additional details about the OP's problem, before make some wild assumption. Really, format your phone? Without even a mention of making a backup, prior to formatting. Kindly read your replies before posting them.